# Flutter web Keycloack login with simple_auth package

Tags: flutter, keycloak, flutter-web

I'm trying to implement Keycloack auth in a Flutter Web application using the simple_auth package (https://pub.dev/packages/simple_auth).

I don't understand the correct way to do that, here my code:

```sh
  import 'package:simple_auth/simple_auth.dart' as simpleAuth;
  ...
  ...
  authenticate() async {
    String identifier = 'keycloak';
    String clientId = 'myclientid';
    String clientSecret = "realm-public-key";
    String redirectUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/';
    String baseUrl = 'https://test-myurl.com/auth/';
    String realm = 'myrealm';
    simpleAuth.KeycloakApi keycloakApi = simpleAuth.KeycloakApi(
        identifier,
        clientId,
        clientSecret,
        redirectUrl,
        baseUrl,
        realm,
        scopes: ['openid', 'profile']
    );
    print(keycloakApi);

    try {
      var response = await keycloakApi.authenticate();
      print(response);
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

I receive this error on startup, when I launch the authenticate function:

```
======== Exception caught by services library============
The following MissingPluginException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel simple_auth_flutter/urlChanged:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel simple_auth_flutter/urlChanged)
```

Someone has an example to follow?
Thanks

Comment: I have a similar problem. From my research SimpleAuth doesn't support Flutter Web. What were your conclusions?

Comment: Humm I don't know, in https://pub.dev/packages/simple_auth appears to be supported but I haven't found any valid example or docs about it.

Comment: If you take a look at https://pub.dev/packages/simple_auth_flutter  - simple auth port that flutter is using, there is no support for Flutter web, and In the issues section https://github.com/Clancey/simple_auth/issues/131 there is a popular question about Flutter web support.

Comment: My solution is manual implementation with REST for now